# how to use single variable instead of using multiple variables in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
Decimal Basic, Da, HRA, CCA, convey, splall, deduction1, deduction2, deduction3, deduction4, deduction5;
Decimal.TryParse(txtBasicSalary.Text, out Basic);
Decimal.TryParse(txtDA.Text, out Da);
Decimal.TryParse(txtHRA.Text, out HRA);
Decimal.TryParse(txtCCA.Text, out CCA);
Decimal.TryParse(txtConvey.Text, out Convey);
Decimal.TryParse(txtSplAll.Text, out splall);
Decimal.TryParse(txtdeduction1.Text, out deduction1);
Decimal.TryParse(txtdeduction2.Text, out deduction2);
Decimal.TryParse(txtdeduction3.Text, out deduction3);
Decimal.TryParse(txtdeduction3.Text, out deduction4);
Decimal.TryParse(txtdeduction5.Text, out deduction5);
drTmp["empl_Basic"] = Basic;
drTmp["empl_DA"] = Da;
drTmp["empl_HRA"] = HRA;
drTmp["empl_CCA"] = CCA;
drTmp["empl_Convey"] = convey;
drTmp["empl_Splall"] = splall;
drTmp["empl_Deduction1"] = deduction1;
drTmp["empl_Deduction2"] = deduction2;
drTmp["empl_Deduction3"] = deduction3;
drTmp["empl_Deduction4"] = deduction4;
drTmp["empl_Deduction5"] = deduction5;
```

I am using above code for decimal convertion, for all text boxes I am using multiple variables and passing that variables, instead of that can I use same variable for all?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the return value of `TryParse`, thus assigning `0M` for invalid data; is that intentional?

Comment: i want use only one variable and use that for all

Comment: i used that above code in pay roll manage ment process for emp sal in formation,in that above i am taking multople variables and i am passing that every text boxess

Comment: instead of that can i take one variable i cant apply for all

Comment: I look forward to receiving $0 on my paycheque because someone in HR typo'd the `txtBasicSalary`.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a utility method:

```
static decimal TryParse(
  string value, decimal @default = 0M)
{
    decimal ret;
    return decimal.TryParse(value, out ret) ? ret : @default;
}
```

and use that:

```
drTmp["empl_Basic"] = TryParse(txtBasicSalary.Text);
drTmp["empl_DA"] = TryParse(txtDA.Text);
drTmp["empl_HRA"] = TryParse(txtHRA.Text);
```

the usage below also allows for non-zero handling of invalid data:

```
drTmp["empl_HRA"] = TryParse(txtHRA.Text, 6.5M);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method if you want, for example as extension method:

```
public static Decimal? TryGetDecimal(this string item)
{
    Decimal d;
    bool success = Decimal.TryParse(item, out d);
    return success ? (Decimal?)d : (Decimal?)null;
}
```

Now you don't need explicit variable declarations at all, just use the return value:

```
drTmp["empl_Basic"] = txtBasicSalary.Text.TryGetDecimal() ?? 0;
drTmp["empl_DA"] = txtDA.Text.TryGetDecimal() ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
I once came across your issue and implemented an extension for the Textbox control.
It's a generic method that can convert do Decimal, int, anything that is a value type.

```
public static T? GetTextOrNullStruct<T>(this TextBox txt, GlobalSist.Common.Utils.ParserCondition? parserCondition, bool throwOnValidation)
    where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return GlobalSist.Common.Utils.Parsers.ConvertStruct<T>(
        GetTextOrNull(txt), parserCondition, throwOnValidation);
}


public static T? ConvertStruct<T>(IConvertible value, ParserCondition? parserCondition, bool throwOnValidation)
    where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    try
    {
        if ((value == null) ||
            (value is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value)))
        {
            if (throwOnValidation)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            else
                return null;
        }
        return Parsers.Convert<T>(value, parserCondition, true);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        if (throwOnValidation)
            throw;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

And here it is the method that converts to a string

```
public static T Convert<T>(IConvertible value, ParserCondition? parserCondition, bool throwOnValidation)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            T convertedValue;
            try
            {
                convertedValue = (T)value.ToType(typeof(T), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (throwOnValidation)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(ex.Message, ex);
                else
                    return default(T);
            }
            return ValidateParserCondition<T>(convertedValue, parserCondition, throwOnValidation);
        }
```

---

edit: Forgot to paste the last called method

---

```
private static T ValidateParserCondition<T>(T value, ParserCondition? parserCondition, bool throwOnValidation)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (parserCondition == null)
        return value;
    else
    {
        int comparingToZero = value.CompareTo(default(T));
        switch (parserCondition.Value)
        {
            case ParserCondition.GreaterOrEqualToZero:
                if (comparingToZero >= 0)
                    return value;
                break;
            case ParserCondition.GreaterThanZero:
                if (comparingToZero > 0)
                    return value;
                break;
            case ParserCondition.LessOrEqualToZero:
                if (comparingToZero <= 0)
                    return value;
                break;
            case ParserCondition.LessThanZero:
                if (comparingToZero < 0)
                    return value;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("ParserCondition at ValidateParserCondition");
        }
        if (throwOnValidation)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                string.Format("value {0} not in accordance with ParserCondition {1}",
                value, parserCondition.Value.ToString()));
        else
            return default(T);
    }

}
```

And the enum declaration is:

```
public enum ParserCondition
{
    /// <summary>
    /// &gt;=0
    /// </summary>
    GreaterOrEqualToZero,
    /// <summary>
    /// &gt;0
    /// </summary>
    GreaterThanZero,
    /// <summary>
    /// &lt;=0
    /// </summary>
    LessOrEqualToZero,
    /// <summary>
    /// &lt;0
    /// </summary>
    LessThanZero,

}
```